# Oracle Apex 18 custom Domains

Tags: oracle-apex

How can I map a domain to Apex Workspaces? For example, I have Instance A, which contains multiple workspaces.

I want workspace A to have Example-A.com.
I want workspace B to have Example-B.com.

I am using oracle apex 18.2 to build applications. Steps I've tried so far:

1. Specifying hostname in the Admin Workspace
2. Tried using CNAME record.

Comment: This is challenging (I have the same issue myself) because you have one instance with multiple domains pointing to it. I don't think you can use CNAMEs for this. I use Apache virtual hosts for each domain which do the initial redirect from each domain to a particular application; however, there's nothing stopping the end user changing the URL to go to another application on the same server (while staying on their domain).

Comment: I guess to limit to a workspace you could use some complex Apache rewrites to append `&c=MYWORKSPACE` to the URL; I'm not sure if this would break anything though. I'm also not sure if it would make any difference to the APEX builder environment login page.

Comment: This is what the Oracle apex docs have pertaining to this issue I’m uncertain if this will work as expected because I haven’t tried it as yet. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e87809/configuring-REST-data-services.htm#AELIG7191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification on what application is executed is done at the application ID level in the form or the f?p=x argument and not at a workspace level.

So you need to setup a proxy or Apache virtual domain in which each of your domains points to the right application with the proper argument.

Comment: Is this the best solution @GasparYYC?

Comment: This works. Was away from the tech field for quite a while. Thanks for the assistance.